# create new column in dataframe using fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataframe in `pandas` where I am using `fuzzywuzzy` package in python to match first column in the dataframe with second column.

I have defined a function to create an output with first column, second column and partial ratio score. But it is not working.

Could you please help

```
import csv
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def match(driver):
    driver["score"]=driver.apply(lambda row: fuzz.partial_ratio(row driver[driver.columns[0]], driver[driver.columns[1]]), axis=1)
    print(driver)
    return(driver)
```

Regards

-Abacus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're passed a Series to work with inside the `apply` function, representing the current row here. In your code, you're effectively ignoring this Series and trying to call `partial_ratio` with the two whole columns of the DataFrame each time (`driver[col]`).

A minor change to your code should hopefully give you what you want.

```
d = DataFrame({'one': ['fuzz', 'wuzz'], 'two': ['fizz', 'woo']})

d.apply(lambda s: fuzz.partial_ratio(s['one'], s['two']), axis=1)

0    75
1    33
dtype: int64
```

(Interestingly, the `partial_ratio` function will accept a Series as input, but only because it converts it internally into a string. :)